# Guidelines for adding 's after name of company ending in s

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, proper-nouns

How about adding 's to the name of a company that ends in s for a possessive?  Is it the same guideline (go by how it would be pronounced)?  Thanks.

Comment: The rules are the same as for any nouns ending in "S."

Comment: Some company names already end in 's.

Comment: It depends on the name. If it's a family name e.g. John Lewis, or a made up one e.g. Toys R Us. The recommendation might be to leave well alone. But otherwise it should be *John Lewis's* and *Toys R Us's*

Comment: What about something that McDonald's owns? Does it become McDonald's'?

Answer (score 1):

In U.S. English, this depends largely on the style guide in use. When a single entity ending in "s" possesses something--say, Toys "R" Us--it can be written as

> Toys "R" Us' products

or

> Toys "R" Us's products

depending on whether you are using an AP-Stylebook-based approach ([source](http://www.grammaruntied.com/?p=816), [source](http://www.apvschicago.com/2011/06/apostrophe-s-vs-apostrophe-forming.html)) or a Chicago-based approach (Sec. 7.18, 15th ed.). If no one has specified style guidelines for you, either way is fine as long as you stay consistent.

Grammar Girl discusses this at some length [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/apostrophe-catastrophe-part-two) and agrees either way is correct.

She also discusses the McDonald's (McDonald's'? McDonald's's?) conundrum [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-make-names-apostrophes-possessive). She says the same thing I would--find a way to rephrase!