# How to put possessive 's after a full company name

Tags: possessives, abbreviations, apostrophe

I need advise on how we correctly use the possessive 's (i.e. apostrophe + s) after a full company name with abbreviation.

E.g., will "Company Name ltd." become "Company Name ltd.'s"? Or is it fine if we leave the "Ltd." out, e.g. "Company Name's"?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232796/guidelines-for-adding-s-after-name-of-company-ending-in-s

Comment: “Company Name's” is common used. Amazon’s assets. Apple’s strategy etc.

Comment: There's no need to add _Ltd_ or its equivalents every time you mention the company's name.

Comment: In what kind of context? Is it a press-release? Or some internal mojo? Or some legalistic document?

Comment: We can and do sometimes extend the "name" to which possessive **'s** is to be attached, especially in informal spoken contexts. It might not look great orthographically, but ***My cousin in London's** wife died recently* certainly wouldn't *sound* "odd" to me.

Comment: One word: reword. I'd go with *My cousin in London recently lost his wife*.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of examples from Google

> Jigsaw Homes Group Ltd.'s Sustainable Finance
> Framework https://www.spglobal.com › research › pdf-articles ›
> 22...
> S&P Global Ratings said that Jigsaw Homes Group Ltd.'s Sustainable Finance Framework is aligned with the: Green Bond Principles (GBP); Green Loan Principles ...

> Here's What Frontline Ltd.'s (NYSE:FRO) Shareholder Ownership Structure Looks Like · What Does The Institutional Ownership Tell Us About ...

and

> Investigation into UK Energy Incubator Hub Ltd's compliance ...https://www.ofgem.gov.uk › publications › investigatio...
> 28 Jul 2022 — See our investigation into UK Energy Incubator Hub Ltd's compliance with multiple licence conditions.

> Parasol Homes Ltd's grading under review - GOV.UK https://www.gov.uk › ... › Housing regulation
> 4 Nov 2021 — Parasol Homes Ltd's grading under review. Providers being investigated for an issue regarding their compliance with the Governance and ...

You pays your money and you takes your choice...

Comment: This does show that an apostrophe can be attached to *Ltd* in this way, but in so far as the OP is seeking practical advice on how to deal with such names, the most important response to the question is the one given by Ms. Bunting in a comment: 'There's no need to add *Ltd* or its equivalents every time you mention the company's name'.  In an article about a business one may, perhaps, state its full name the first time it is referred to (although even that may be unnecessary if it is well known), and then use some short form of it afterwards.

Comment: You can find almost anything online, doesn't mean it's a good idea though.

Comment: @jsw29 It is useful in contracts and other important documents to distinguish between the owner John Smith and the entity John Smith Ltd.

Comment: @StuartF, I'm not sure poisoning the well is valid. The point is that both are used, hence the final line.

Comment: Not everything online is done by a competent English speaker/writer. There are a lot of auto-translated and auto-generated texts, as well as texts written by people of different degrees of proficiency. If you're going to accept every string of characters on the basis that it probably occurs somewhere, then questions like this are meaningless.

Comment: @StuartF *Not everything online is done by a competent English speaker/writer.* this may be true, but the question you have not addressed *in this case* is "How do we know which is correct?"

Answer (score 0):

> E.g., will "Company Name ltd." become "Company Name ltd.'s"?

Yes, when a proper noun consists of multiple words, the convention is to add the possessive clitic to the last word. [CMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style) gives the examples *doctor of philosophy's* and *the mayor of Chicago's* (14th edition, section 6.22). There is no exception for company names or abbreviations such as "ltd." (By the way, "ltd" would usually begin with a capital letter in a company name.)

---

> Or is it fine if we leave the "Ltd." out, e.g. "Company Name's"?

Yes, it is very common to drop "Ltd." and similar parts of company names when they are not needed. For example:

> By denying to hear Tesla’s appeal, the state Supreme Court allowed that lawsuit to proceed. (Melody Petersen, "[State agency asks court to order Tesla to cooperate in discrimination investigation](https://www.latimes.com/business/story/2023-04-13/state-asks-court-to-force-tesla-to-provide-information-in-discrimination-case)," *Los Angeles Times*, 13 April 2023)

(The company's full name is [Tesla, Inc.](https://calcivilrights.ca.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/32/2023/04/CRDTeslaPMKPetitiontoCompel_filed.pdf))